# Magento 2 : Add to compare and add to wishlist with ajax

Tags: magento2, ajax

How to do add to compare and add to wishlist functionality using ajax.
I want to do ajax functionality for wishlist and compare in homepage hot seller block products and listing page products.

Without reload page using ajax add to wishlist and add to compare functionality.

Comment: Hi, did you get the solution or any helpful resources?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't want to advertise anything but Tigren ajax compare and wishlist module has fulfilled our requirements. Oh and also it is free and includes ajax add to cart and customer login functions too.

https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-extensions/ajax-suite-magento-2/

Comment: Can try with this extension: https://github.com/boolfly/ajax-wishlist

Answer (score 6):

I have added Ajax add to wishlist functionality on product page following below method:

Added custom "Add to wishlist" button to following file inside `<?php if ($block->isWishListAllowed()) : ?>` condition

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/Module/Magento_Wishlist/templates/catalog/product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml**

```
<button name="add-to-wishlist" onclick="addProductToWishlist()"> Add to Wishlist</button>
<?php $productId = json_decode($block->getWishlistParams(), true)['data']['product']; ?>
```

It calls `addProductToWishlist()` javascript function which I have added in the same **wishlist.phtml** file

```
<script>
function addProductToWishlist() {
    require(["jquery"], function($){
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('general/index/addtowishlist') ?>',
            method: 'get',
            data: { productId: <?php echo $productId ?>},
            dataType: 'json',
            showLoader:true,
            success: function(data){
                var redirect = data.result.redirect;
                if(redirect) {
                    window.location.href = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/login') ?>';
                } else {
                  // show successfully added message 
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Here is my controller code which has logic of adding product to wishlist.

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Addtowishlist.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\General\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Addtowishlist extends Action {

    protected $customerSession;
    protected $wishlistRepository;
    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    ResultFactory $resultFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory
        ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->wishlistRepository= $wishlistRepository;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        if(!$customerId) {
           $jsonData = ['result' => ['status' => 200, 'redirect' => 1,'message' => 'Customer not logged in.']]; 
            $result = $this->jsonFactory->create()->setData($jsonData);
            return $result;
        }
        $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productId');

        try {
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $product = null;
        }

        $wishlist = $this->wishlistRepository->create()->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true);

        $wishlist->addNewItem($product);
        $wishlist->save();

        $jsonData = ['result' => ['status' => 200, 'redirect' => 0, 'message' => 'Added to wishlist']];
        $result = $this->jsonFactory->create()->setData($jsonData);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Above code works fine on product page. Similar way you can add Ajax add to wishlist functionality on listing page.

**`Note:`** Above code needs some improvement like validating `form_key` in controller file.

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to come up with a fairly simple solution for AJAX Wishlist functionality:

1) Use the following helper method which returns JSON-encoded parameters:

`$this->helper("Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data")->getAddParams($product)`

This returns something like the following:

```
{
    "action": "https://www.mywebsite.com/wishlist/index/add/",
    "data": {
        "product": "1",
        "uenc": "a0bLy9tMhZGlhLWVsZXljbGFya2oZWxY29tL25i5hc3RsZW1lbnRzLXNUusLmhHR0cHM6Ww,"
    }
}
```

2) Include the form key in your data when making a POST request, similar to the following:

```
var url  = "https://www.mywebsite.com/wishlist/index/add/";
var data = {
    action   : "add-to-wishlist",
    form_key : "xyC5IcaqeNg2um6g",
    product  : "1",
    uenc     : "a0bLy9tMhZGlhLWVsZXljbGFya2oZWxY29tL25i5hc3RsZW1lbnRzLXNUusLmhHR0cHM6Ww,"
}

$.post(url, data);
```

The item should now be in your wishlist.

Note: the form key can be obtained either via JavaScript by getting the value of a cookie called `form_key` or through Magento's `getFormKey()` function.

**Edit:** there are a couple of drawbacks when using this method:

1. There's no `success` callback from the POST request.
2. Once you add an item, you'll see a message on the next page you visit saying *"[item] has been added to your Wish List. Click here to continue shopping."*

So although this works, it's far from a robust solution.

Comment: Perfect answer with explanation ! wonderful! made my day! +1 :)