# How to add ajax to custom theme add-to-cart and Wishlist button?

Tags: magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce

I created my website using a custom theme, how to implement ajax to my add-to-cart and wishlist button?

I tried the following step, it not working,

vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml (For testing purpose added in core files)

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {},
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: My console https://snipboard.io/MBWrqc.jpg, i can't find a relevant error, some of the error i am facing before itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@zus I would suggest to review the below post where you can get your question answer easily. Here you will find an extension option as well as a customization option. But I would suggest to go with the extension option.

[Magento 2 : Add to compare and add to wishlist with ajax](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102781/magento-2-add-to-compare-and-add-to-wishlist-with-ajax/231853)

https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-extensions/ajax-suite-magento-2/

Please let me know if this will not help.

Comment: When i intall fist time why i am getting this error : PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Tigren\Core\API\License\LicenseAPI, because the name is already in use in C:\xampp\htdocs\m3\app\code\Tigren\Ajaxcompare\view\frontend\web\css\source\LicenseAPI\LicenseApi.php on line 14

Comment: It means that the extension is already installed. Can you please check in the backend and see, if it is already installed, then you just need to configure it.

Comment: This is my first install.

Comment: Then you need to debug and fix the issue because in the free module it may have an issue. In this case what you can do, go to that file lone number and find that class name in whole module, if you find the same class name in another file then change class name and see it is working or not. Please let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: I have installed that module and it seems there is an issue in module. I would suggest, remove LicenseAPI condition from every module registration.php file. It will solve your problem.

Comment: You mean this whole condition : https://codeshare.io/5X6qzk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120907/discussion-between-zus-and-nits).

Comment: bro, am right...?

Comment: Yes correct Please remove from all the registration.php file

Comment: Thank you nits.

Comment: Welcome @zus :)